# Switching two optocouplers based on different voltages

Tags: design, opto-isolator

I want to build a (I think) simple circuit where I want to transmit the state of two switches across two wires (ground and live). Let's say I have a circuit with which I can set three output voltages between these two wires from the two switches (switch A pressed, switch B pressed, both pressed): 1V, 2V and 3V. How would I go about driving two optocouplers so that when the 'input' voltage is 1V, optocoupler 1 is 'closed' (if that's the right word); when the input is 2V, optocoupler 2 is closed; and when the voltage is 3V, both are closed? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly different way to solve your problem is to use AC and handle the two halves differently, as in the circuit below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0jRuw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A variation on this circuit was used in trick electrical circuits where all wires were visible - two switches and two incandescent bulbs- connected to the mains. Diodes are hidden in the bases of the bulbs and the switches. Each switch controls a lamp independently. If they don't notice the lowered brightness for wattage, head scratching may ensue.

Comment: Very interesting. Maybe what I'm about to say is heresy - but could this work using 230V directly? So that I wouldn't need a power converter at all?

Comment: Better to use a 230:12VAC transformer, for safety.

Comment: Right, I found that there are very small 230:12VAC transformers that are very cheap too. Then one last question: wouldn't the AC cause a chopped-off (because of the minimum voltage to switch the optocoupler) half-sinewave signal as a result? Can I put in a capacitor there to smooth the output signal? How would I calculate the value the capacitor should be? (sorry for noob questions)

Comment: I'd rather put the smoothing at the secondary side of the optocoupler.

Comment: @Spehro I knew about that old trick circuit, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution (schematic-wise) is a microcontroller with an ADC and a few lines of code that read the input voltage and control two outputs.

Other than that, you could use a quad comparator LM339. Set the thresholds at, say, 0.5V and 1.5V and 2.5V with a simple 4-resistor divider (say 499/1K/1K/2.49K to +5V).

Then you have three outputs - either can be true or inverted based on which way the inputs are connected. Use a 74HC02 to straighten out the logic and drive the optos and you're done. Two 14 pin chips and four resistors (plus 3 pull-ups and 2 series resistors for the optos).

Call the comparisons A, B, C and connect it so you get /A, B and /C, and the logic should be obvious.

Comment: But to use a microcontroller, I'd need to power it, right? I'd prefer to power the whole thing from the 'sender' so to say, so that I don't need a separate power supply at the 'receiver' side. I will look into the quad comparator, thank you.

Comment: Quad comparator will need power too.

Comment: You can't easily operate an opto from ~1V. It's possible to step up 0.9V ~ 3V to 5V or whatever, but it might be easier to rethink the approach.